# Gallery Folders Cover photo using C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing my project in ASP.NET MVC 4 using C#. I have a gallery page in my website. For listing each album folders in the gallery folder I use the following code,

Model:

```
public List<string> GetGalleryName(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    DirectoryInfo[] subdir = di.GetDirectories();
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subdir)
    {
        files.Add(dir.Name);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Gallery()
{
    string folderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Gallery");
    List<String> currentimage = new Gallery().GetGalleryName(folderpath);
    return View(currentimage);
}
```

cshtml:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<a href="~/Home/Show?foldername=@item"> <div class="galframe"><div class="galframepic"></div><div class="galframecaption"><p>@item</p></div></div></a>
}
```

I want to set the cover pages or each of the album folders by using the images inside that particular folder (like Facebook albums). Actually, one of the image from that particular folder is shown as background of div "galframepic". How might I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have used asp.net webform to do almost same type of task. I am sharing my workflow, see if it helps you a bit.

```
1. Create an entry form for album. In this form there will be two input fields
  a) Album name field of type text
  b) file type input field.
  c) when album name is given and an image file is uploaded to a certain directory then save  the directoryPath+imageFileName in your database along with the Album name.

2) In another page fetch the previously save data for the album from database. And use image that was uploaded in the directory as the cover folder of the album. you can also show the album name that is fetched along with the (directoryPath+imageFileName) below the image.
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks.